# issue with storing an api response in vue-cli project

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, frontend

i had some hard time yesterday figuring out a strange behavior  in vue-js 
basically i had an simple api-call that returns a collection of data and it works fine 
the problem now that i have to call it like 4 times with different parameters 
so i figured out i might add this parameter and then save them 
but when i ever try to assign the return it returns undefined. 
here is a sample of my code

```js
data(){
    return {
      token:'',
      availableOrders:'',
      waiting :'',
      to_store :'',
      to_client :'',
      finished :'',
      noData:true,
    }
  },
methods: {
    // the function that calls the api
    getAllOrders: function (param){
      param = param || undefined;
      axios.get( window.bassUrl + 'orders',
      { headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' , 'Authorization' : `Bearer ${this.token}`},params: { 'type': param }},
      ).then(
          (response) => {
          if (response.data.code == 202) {
                let responseArray= response.data.data.items;
                this.availableOrders = responseArray;
                let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseArray));
                return result
              } else {
                console.log(response.data);
              }
          }
      ).catch(
          (error) => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      )
  }
  }
```

and i ran this method in the mounted() method like so :

```js
mounted(){
       this.token=localStorage.getItem('token');
       this.finished = this.getAllOrders('finished')
       this.to_store = this.getAllOrders('to_store');
       this.to_client =  this.getAllOrders('to_client');
       this.waiting =  this.getAllOrders('waiting');
       console.log(this.finished);
  }
```

**The problem here is whenever i try to run this the console returns "undefined" what have i done wrong ?**

also i am new to vuejs if you have any suggestion to enhance this code i am totally OK with it, thanks

Comment: i think it is something wrong when you write axios.get(bassUrl) what is bassUrl???

Comment: it has nothing to t=do with axios the api returns the data just fine, the problem with me try to bind the response data to any of the variables